# Need Help About Using Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, windows, putty

I am using ubuntu in dual boot with windows. I decide to completely move into ubuntu. But a little problem occurs. I am learning to manage server so I am working with a vps. In windows to login SSH I use putty. But I need to know for ubuntu how I can login SSH?

Regards,
Mahbub

Answer (score 0):

goto the terminal and type in

```
    $ ssh <username>@<computer name or IP address>
```

more information at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/ConnectingTo